# Custom post Types slug and permalinks issue - SEO and Structure

Tags: wordpress, url, seo, custom-post-type, permalinks

I see this issue has been brought up before but they don't seem to address my specific issue. I do feel my specific issue is a broad one though. That may seem paradoxical but hear me out.

For a site I'm working on in WordPress, I created some pages for the counties they serve. So far I have one for Bucks, Montgomery, and Delaware Counties, but there will be plenty more. From there we want people to be able to navigate to "Recent Jobs" based on the county that the client can add themselves. So it can be 1 to however many jobs the client wants to add. These pages will talk about a specific job in a specific town, then link to "Related Jobs" by job type, not county. So these go 3 levels deep, County Hub page > Specific job in specific town > Specific job type (ie: Bucks County, PA > Window Replacement Job in Newtown, PA > Window Replacement Job in Wherever).

Hope that makes sense. So what I did was create a Page for each County. Then I created a Custom Post type: County Jobs. I created custom taxonomies for each county to group them by county. I will probably need taxonomies to group them by job type also but I'm not there yet. I set up my template "single-county-job.php" and my Custom Fields to display only on this post type. The problem came when "/county-job/", the post type slug, displays in the URL. Adding that extra level is bad for SEO rankings. If you so a search for anything in Google you will see the first pages of results show sites that go only two levels deep: "URL.com/level1/level2" and anything with "/level3/" is at best on the third page (besides sites like Amazon or eBay). I ideally want the URL to be: "/bucks-county-pa/post-title" not "/county-job/bucks-county-pa/post-title". It also doesn't make sense for a user to go from the "/bucks-county/" page to "/county-job/bucks-county-pa/post-title".

So I found multiple ways to get the slug out of the URL but all result in a 404. Basically WordPress no longer recognizes the post as a post. There are some redirect rules I can add to get around the 404s but that is not good for SEO either. I also read it is bad practice, a hack, and shouldn't be done.

Have you set up similar pages/posts in the past and how did you handle it? That slug is a problem, but making a CPT for each county is not an option either because there are way too many and they would all be the same set up - it just doesn't make sense. Maybe this shouldn't be a CPT, but then how do I handle it? It doesn't seem like they should be pages, and how would I handle the Custom Fields?

I am stuck! Any help or insight you could provide would be a huge help.

Comment: Hold on what's `bucks-county-pa` in this context? It's the county name?

Comment: Right that would be the county name. So far I have three counties but there will eventually be 20+. The three so far are `/bucks-county-pa/, /delaware-county-pa/, /montgomery-county-pa/`. Then later we will have other counties in PA, NJ, and DE. Right now I have them set up as taxonomies but ultimately - given a suggested solution - I'm not sure what they would need to be. I just know for sure they would need to be part of the URL.

Comment: So the slug structure is `[county name]-county-[state code]`, right? So you'll always have "county" in the slug?

Comment: Right. :) That's how we will organize the cities in which the jobs were performed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Considering that the word `county` is static in your url, you can use it in order to make Wordpress recognize what you're trying to request. You can use [`generate_rewrite_rules`](https://codex.wordpress.org/Plugin_API/Action_Reference/generate_rewrite_rules) filter in order to add your own rewrite rule:

```
add_filter('generate_rewrite_rules', 'my_rewrite', 9);
function my_rewrite($wp_rewrite)
{
    $wp_rewrite->rules = array_merge(array(
        '^([^-]*)-county-([^/]*)/([^/]*)/?$' => 'index.php?post_type=county-job&county=$matches[1]-county-$matches[2]&county-job‌​=$matches[3]'
    ), $wp_rewrite->rules);
}
```

The second important part is to tell Worpdress to not use anymore links with `/county-job/` as prefix. You can do this with the [`post_type_link`](https://codex.wordpress.org/Plugin_API/Filter_Reference/post_type_link) filter:

```
add_filter('post_type_link', 'my_post_link', 1, 3);
add_filter('post_link', 'my_post_link', 10, 3);
add_filter('page_link', 'my_post_link', 10, 3);
function my_post_link($post_link, $id = 0) {
  $post = get_post($id);
  if(is_object($post) && $post->post_type == 'job') {
      return str_replace('county-job/', '', $post_link);
  }
  return $post_link;
}
```

Don't forget that you need to flush your rewrite rules in order to make this script working. You can do this by visiting the Permalinks section in WP back office.

Comment: Hi vard and thanks for the well articulated solution - but the redirect is really not ideal for reasons I stated above. I would like to be able to set this up without any hacks. I'm totally open to your ideas though if there is a reason you think this is a clean, good practice solution. I'm still learning. Could you explain why I should do it this way?

Comment: Well the thing is that Wordpress **need** a prefix for a custom post type - the prefix of your url is get from your CPT definition and used by WP to know wich archive page to call. So if we remove this information from the url, Wordpress doesn't have any way out of the box to know which CPT to refer - he's lost. In my opinion the rewrite rule is a valid solution and shouldn't be consider as a hack - it doesn't rewrite the old url to the new one, he just tell wordpress a new way to access your CPT elements.

Comment: OK let me just make sure I understand you - so you're saying that this rewrite rule is not a redirect in the way I'm thinking, like say a 301? It's not "take this URL and go here instead" it's more like "here's how to get here"?

Comment: Nope it's not a 301 it's just a rewrite - WP use this kind of rewrite all the time in order to get all the requests to _index.php_ with the correct query string.

Comment: Ah ha! So a rewrite will happen before the browser gets the page, so this is SEO safe. Thank you! I'm going to try this right now, and if it works I will check your answer if not I will be back with questions. :) Still seems like an unnecessary work around but you're right that it doesn't seem like a hack. I think this is a limitation in how WP handles CPT.

Comment: Here is the code I'm using in combination with yours: [link](http://hastebin.com/hiverodaye.coffee). This gets rid of the slug and yours redirects to the homepage. My CPT permalink structure is this: `/county-job/%county%/%postname%/`. Except the /county-job/ part is now hidden. I'm reading about WP rewrites and adjusting the code you provided with no luck. Would you be able to point me in the right direction? I am so close!!!

Comment: Well as I told you in my answer `index.php?post_type=jobs&county_slug=$matches[1]&job_title=$matches[2]` should be changed to the **actual** query string - this query string is not valid and this is why it redirects to homepage (this was just an example). I suggest you to go to a job page with the old url and do a `var_dump` of `$_GET` in order to get the real query string.

Comment: Thanks for your patience here. I did: `global $wp_query;
var_dump($wp_query->query_vars);` and got this result [link](http://hastebin.com/bizejeqawi.coffee) but I honestly have no idea how to apply that info to the query string. Did I do the right thing?

Comment: Try with this : `index.php?post_type=county-job&county=$matches[1]&county-job=$matches[2]`

Comment: That didn't work :-/ You seem to really know your stuff, is this something you have done before? I'm not an expert and I think it's clear you know more than me, but I'm starting to think this isn't possible with CPT.

Comment: Did you flushed your rules after updating the rule? And yes I set up this kind of configuration few times, CPT rewrite in multilingual, and it worked like a charm :)

Comment: I recruited my boss and we figured it out using the code you provided :-D! So I'm marking your answer as correct but here is the string I had to use: `index.php?post_type=county-job&county=$matches[1]-county-$matches[2]&county-job=$matches[3]` and I had to add more filters to make sure that wherever the link could possibly be generated the URL would display without `county-job` example: `add_filter( 'post_link', 'my_post_link', 10, 3);
add_filter( 'page_link', 'my_post_link', 10, 3);
add_filter( 'post_type_link', 'my_post_link', 10, 3);` Thanks for all of your help!

Comment: Glad it works for you :) I updated my answer with your returns. Cheers!